# Show selected rows as columns when populating a listbox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I'm trying to populate a listbox with a range of cells from **Excel**.

My dataset has way more categories (about 120) than actual data (about 25) therefore I chose to list the categories in rows, and the actual data in each column. This way I don't have to scroll left and right so much, rather just up and down.

I would like to be able to make a listbox that shows **"only certain selected rows"** (e.g rows 2,5,6) as columns in my listbox and their corresponding data as rows in my listbox.

Is this possible?

Comment: OK, either I shouldn't be answering this question, or you have Rows and Columns mixed up in your description. It seems your sheet has about 120 values down (ROWS of data) and about 25 values across (COLUMNS of data.) Right?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Modify as needed, of course:

```
Sub FillListBox()
    Dim a() As Variant
    a = Range("A1:D4")

    'Test work area is range("A1:D4")
    'on Sheet1
    'Sheet1 has a Listbox named "ListBox1"

    With Sheets(1).ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 3    ' set the number of columns in the Listbox
        .List = Application.Index(Application.Transpose(a), _
                   Application.Evaluate( _
                   "Row(1:" & UBound(a) & ")"), Array(1, 3, 4))
        'Array(1, 3, 4)just above are the three rows to put into the
        'listbox
    End With
End Sub
```